# Is there any way to sort things by date using requests and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

Just like in the topic. My code look like this. Everything works but it seems like the dictionary is cut somewhere. Newest CVE's are from 2016... not 2020. Just like on this screen below. What's the problem here? How can i get to the 2020 CVE's? Does Pycharm cannot load the rest of them? I tried to run this in cmd but the result was even worse, it was cut in 2014. What can I do about it?

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

keyword = 'oracle'
url = 'https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword={}'.format(keyword)
html_data = requests.get(url).text

df = pd.read_html(html_data)
data = df[2].to_dict(orient='records')

for dict in data:
    for key in dict:
        print(key, dict[key])
```

[image]

This is how it look like on cve.mitre.org

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best to use it as a DataFrame, then you can filter on columns:

```
keyword = 'oracle'
url = 'https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword={}'.format(keyword)
html_data = requests.get(url).text

df = pd.read_html(html_data)
df = df[2]
df['Year'] = df['Name'].str.split('-').str[1].astype(int)
df = df[df['Year']>2016]
print(df)


                  Name                                        Description  Year
0        CVE-2020-9402  Django 1.11 before 1.11.29, 2.2 before 2.2.11,...  2020
1        CVE-2020-9315  ** PRODUCT NOT SUPPORTED WHEN ASSIGNED ** Orac...  2020
2        CVE-2020-9314  ** PRODUCT NOT SUPPORTED WHEN ASSIGNED ** Orac...  2020
3        CVE-2020-8428  fs/namei.c in the Linux kernel before 5.5 has ...  2020
4        CVE-2020-7221  mysql_install_db in MariaDB 10.4.7 through 10....  2020
...                ...                                                ...   ...
2632    CVE-2017-10001  Vulnerability in the Oracle Hospitality Simpho...  2017
2633  CVE-2017-1000030  Oracle, GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3...  2017
2634  CVE-2017-1000029  Oracle, GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3...  2017
2635  CVE-2017-1000028  Oracle, GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4...  2017
2636    CVE-2017-10000  Vulnerability in the Oracle Hospitality Report...  2017
```

Comment: Cool, if that worked you can mark this as the answer and consider upvoting

Comment: But what if I will try to send this to a database? I think that format isnt easy as a dictionary from python. Am i right or wrong? Any sugestions?

Comment: I don't want to just analize this data, I want to send it to database and then be able export this to different formats via web application. I hope you understand me.

Comment: You should be able to easily add a pandas data frame to any database. Check out pyodbc.

Comment: Ok, I'll check every possibility and I will give you a feedback. Wish me good luck.